# how can I disable exponential notation when selecting a float from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, floating-point

I have a FLOAT column that contains some very small numbers like 0.00000000000234

When I select them in MySQL, I get them back in exponential notation like 2.34e-13. Is there any way I can modify the formatting of these numbers to force MySQL to return it as 0.00000000000234 ?

Ultimately what I'd be looking to do is modify the display, not the underlying representation of the number. So it would probably be a display or formatting setting. MySQL has a FORMAT() function, but it's nothing like what I want (it puts numbers in format like 123,456.78).

Comment: mysql does not format the numbers, it returns actual floats. What frontend / UI are you using to display the results?

Comment: @sehe, actually MySQL does format the numbers into exponential notation if you have a lot of zeros at the front of your (<1) decimal. I get this result using the built-in MySQL client. SELECT mycol FROM table WHERE id = 1, mycol will become exponential.

Comment: So the `builtin` client (that is not builtin, but I get what you mean) does the formatting. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 4):

You can coerce the number back to the desired display format. Cast it to a large enough DECIMAL value and then cast the DECIMAL to a CHAR in order to get the display form you are after. This is purely display and allows you to continue to store floats in mysql (if so desired).

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(CAST(f AS DECIMAL(14,14)) AS CHAR) AS example from test;
+------------------+
| example          |
+------------------+
| 0.00000000000234 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You will lose some precision of course, depending on the value.

Comment: Thanks :) My first bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `DECIMAL` to store those values, as float values are all approximated, and are inaccurate when dealing with such small numbers. A `DECIMAL` would be displayed as you want.

Comment: My impression was that FLOAT was only inaccurate if you have a lot of significant digits, not if you simply have a very large or small number. In these cases, I only have 3-5 significant digits, and I'm just doing storage and retrieval.

Comment: I did try using a Decimal and that did work. I'm not sure that I want to change all of my Floats to Decimals, so still hoping to figure out a way to change the formatting. But this does help.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, this won't work because one of the requirements of my application is that numbers be formatted to contain arbitrary numbers of decimals, but not to have trailing zeros. So for example I want 2.345 and 4.5 in the same column, not 4.500. So Decimal isn't an option for me. I need to somehow eliminate the exponential notation from the floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can use round. i.e.

select round(column,10) from foo;