# Disable scientific notation in MySQL command-line client?

Tags: mysql, command-line, formatting, scientific-notation

I have a MySQL table with many numeric columns (some INT, some FLOAT).  I would like to query it with the MySQL command-line client (specifically, `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1`), like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo;
```

Unfortunately, if the value of any numeric field exceeds 10^6, this client displays the result in scientific notation, which makes reading the results difficult.

I could correct the problem by FORMAT-ing each of the fields in my query, but there are many of them and many tables I would like to query.  Instead I'm hoping to find a client variable or flag I can set to disable scientific notation for all queries.

I have not been able to find one in the `--help` or the `man` page, nor searching Google or this site.  Instead all I find are discussions of preserving/removing scientific notation when using `<insert-programming-language>`'s MySQL API.

Thank you for any tips.

::edit::

Here's an example table ...

```
mysql> desc foo;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| date         | date        | NO   | PRI | NULL              |
| name         | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |
| val          | float       | NO   |     | NULL              |
| last_updated | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+
```

and some example values ...

```
mysql> select * from foo where date='20120207';
+------------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| date       | name   | val          | last_updated        |
+------------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| 2012-02-07 | A      |      88779.5 | 2012-02-07 13:38:14 |
| 2012-02-07 | B      |  1.00254e+06 | 2012-02-07 13:38:14 |
| 2012-02-07 | C      |      78706.5 | 2012-02-07 13:38:15 |
+------------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Now, the actual values I loaded into the third field are:

```
88779.5, 1002539.25, 78706.5390625
```

and they can be seen exactly if I manipulate the value:

```
mysql> select date, name, ROUND(val, 10), last_updated from foo where ...
+------------+---+--------------------+---------------------+
| 2012-02-07 | A |   88779.5000000000 | 2012-02-07 13:38:14 |
| 2012-02-07 | B | 1002539.2500000000 | 2012-02-07 13:38:14 |
| 2012-02-07 | C |   78706.5390625000 | 2012-02-07 13:38:15 |
```

Something in the client seems to be enforcing that I only be allowed to see six significant figures, even though there are more in the table.

If a query such as

```
mysql> select ROUND(*, 2) from foo ...
```

were possible, that would be great!  Otherwise I can't really take the time to individually wrap 100 column names in "ROUND()" whenever I need to inspect some data.

Interestingly, I occasionally use a phpMyAdmin interface to browse the contents of some of these tables, and that interface also has this 6 significant figure limitation.  So it's not limited to just the CLI.

Comment: Scientific notation was created in order make large decmial values EASIER to read.

Comment: I think you're out of luck here. I don't believe the CLI makes this an option.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but it's HARDER to read those values when mixed in with values that are not in scientific notation.

Comment: An acceptable solution would be an equivalent to SQL*Plus's FORMAT and NUMFORMAT settings that can be placed in login.sql.  But I can't seem to find any equivalent for those in MySQL. :(

Comment: Can you show an example of the table you are using?  I'm using this one: `create table testLength( i int);`  And there doesn't seem to be an issue with the command line client bringing back the exploded values.

Comment: I added an example schema and data into the original post.  The real tables of course have a lot more columns.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077069/how-can-i-disable-exponential-notation-when-selecting-a-float-from-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the link, JYelton.  I searched a lot of terms, but not "exponential notation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after reading the documentation more thoroughly, I still can't see any reason why a client would limit itself to displaying only 6 sig figs from a FLOAT (especially when the table itself is definitely storing more).

Nonetheless, an acceptable solution (for this weary user) is to change all my tables to use DECIMAL(16,4) instead of FLOAT.  Unfortunately, this makes all my numbers show up with 4 decimal places (even if they're all '0').  But at least all numbers have the same width now, and my client never displays them in scientific notation or limits the number of sig figs in its output.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the CAST function allow you to request that the values for a certain field are returned as DECIMAL ? Not an expert and haven't tried it, but that would be the first thing I try.

Comment: Yes, that's as good as any other per-field suggestion.  The question, however, is how to avoid using any per-field operation to get the results in the correct format.  I want to be able to write select * from foo ... and not see any scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this helped me.. I used a view..

```
create view foo2 as select date, name, ROUND(val, 10) val, last_updated from foo
```

Then just do your queries on foo2. also works in phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks. This is not a bad solution but does introduce VIEWs (which are not a good thing in MySQL).